# How to generate rustdoc documentation for the [build-dependencies] in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I am working on a small project that uses a build.rs file intensively. It seems that `cargo doc --all` generates the documentation for the `[dependencies]` but not for the `[build-dependencies]` in Cargo.toml.

How can I generate the offline documentation for the build-dependency crates?

Comment: `--all` is unneeded unless you have a workspace

Answer (score 3):

You cannot:

- [Optionally document dev-dependencies (3475)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3475)

In the meantime, move it temporarily to `[dependencies]` to generate the docs or make a new project just for docs.